# Bluetooth adapter not found ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, bluetooth, kde

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 Lts on Macbook Pro early 2015 edition and have tried a few other gnome and kde distros, all has the same problem of bluetooth being missing after restart. Sometimes it shows up but more often doesn't.

The systemctl bluetooth status is always as active but in the settings it shows like no bluetooth adapter found

> $ systemctl status bluetooth
> ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena>
> Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-31 07:59:52 IST; 10min ago
> Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
> Main PID: 1106 (bluetoothd)
> Status: "Running"
> Tasks: 1 (limit: 9331)
> Memory: 1.9M
> CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
> └─1106 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Aug 31 07:59:52 abubk-MBP systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/787zE.png): Starting Bluetooth service...
Aug 31 07:59:52 abubk-MBP bluetoothd[1106]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Aug 31 07:59:52 abubk-MBP systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/787zE.png): Started Bluetooth service.
Aug 31 07:59:52 abubk-MBP bluetoothd[1106]: Starting SDP server
Aug 31 07:59:52 abubk-MBP bluetoothd[1106]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initial>

[settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/787zE.png)

> lspci | grep Bluetooth

Doesn't give any results

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, from YouTube advice, reset SMC, shutdown computer > remove battery > hold down power button for 5 sec. > install battery > startup. This could be an option.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?